# error vector iterators incompatible - opencv

Tags: c++, exception, opencv, vector, iterator

I am trying to calibrate my camera using opencv.  I found [this](http://www.aishack.in/2010/07/calibrating-undistorting-with-opencv-in-c-oh-yeah/) tutorial, but I am experiencing an "error vector iterators incompatible" exception.

I declared the image_points as follows:

```
vector<vector<Point2f>> image_points;
```

the corners as follows:

```
vector<Point2f> corners;
```

used the corners in the following 3 OpenCV calls:

```
    bool found = findChessboardCorners(image, board_sz, corners, CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS);

    if(found)
    {
        cornerSubPix(gray_image, corners, Size(11, 11), Size(-1, -1), TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS | CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1));
        drawChessboardCorners(gray_image, board_sz, corners, found);
    }
```

and got the exception when trying to push the corners on the image_points like this:

```
if ( key == ' ' && found != 0 )
    image_points.push_back(corners);
```

Can anyone hint to what is wrong?

**EDIT** : posting full code

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numBoards = 3;
    int numCornersHor = 9;
    int numCornersVer = 6;

    int numSquares = numCornersHor * numCornersVer;
    Size board_sz = Size(numCornersHor, numCornersVer);

    VideoCapture capture = VideoCapture(0);

    vector<vector<Point3f>> object_points;
    vector<vector<Point2f>> image_points;

    vector<Point2f> corners;
    int successes=0;

    Mat image;
    Mat gray_image;
    capture >> image;

    vector<Point3f> obj;
    for(int j=0;j<numSquares;j++)
        obj.push_back( Point3f( (j * 1.0f) / numCornersHor, ( j % numCornersHor ) * 1.0f, 0.0f ) );

    while(successes < numBoards)
    {
        cvtColor(image, gray_image, CV_BGR2GRAY);

        bool found = findChessboardCorners(image, board_sz, corners, CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS);

        if(found)
        {
            cornerSubPix(gray_image, corners, Size(11, 11), Size(-1, -1), TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS | CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1));
            drawChessboardCorners(gray_image, board_sz, corners, found);
        }

        imshow("win2", gray_image);

        capture >> image;

        int key = waitKey(1);
        if(key==27)
            return 0;

        if(key==' ' && found!=0)
        {
            // the next line throws the exception.
            image_points.push_back(corners);
            object_points.push_back(obj);
            printf("Snap stored!\n");

            successes++;

            if(successes>=numBoards)
                break;
        }
    }
    // the program never reaches this point

    // do more stuff .....
}
```

The below is the exception that I am experiencing.
[image: exception encountered]

Comment: Code looks good to me. Perhaps post complete code and exact error message.

Comment: We need more information than this.  What does findChessboardCorners do? (perhaps it is in your link, but put it here) What are all those arguments to it?  Here's my guess.  Somewhere in your code, you are trying to compare iterators from two separate vectors.  That's undefined behavior.  In some implementations, if you compile in debug mode, it will raise an exception.  In other implementations, or if you take it out of debug mode, you will get an indecipherable error.

Comment: This program should locate the corners of a chessboard from the images captured by a webcam.  It will, then draw them out on the image that is displayed on screen.  This information will then be used to calibrate the camera to be able to remove the camera distortion from images.  findChessboardCorners is the function that finds the corners of the chessboard, and is part of the OpenCV 3D calibration library.

Comment: We need to see the actual code for `cornerSubPix`, `findChessboardCorners`, and `drawChessboardCorners`. The error is apparently occurring in one of those functions, but there's no way to help you without seeing how they're implemented.

Comment: To me it suggests that the corners vector is corrupt, presumably by one of the routines findChessboardCorners, cornerSubPix or drawChessboardCorners.

Comment: @ildjarn all three functions you mention are part of the OpenCV 3D Calibration library (i.e. not my code).  The code is available on sourceforge.

Comment: A quick google suggests that findChessboardCorners has some bugs. Including crashes when people try to use the returned vector.

Comment: Why do you think error is here: `image_points.push_back(corners);` ? In the message box I do not see it refers to this line.

Comment: @PiotrNycz - Simple ... I debugged, and the exception occurred during the execution of that line